# Unable to decipher this Ruby line containing map operator

Tags: ruby, reflection, class-eval

I've just seen this line of Ruby code in [ruby-trello](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello/blob/master/lib/trello/action.rb):

```
# Returns the member who created the action.
one :member_creator, :via => Member, :using => :member_creator_id
```

It seems to relate to a [superclass](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello/blob/master/lib/trello/basic_data.rb) method defined as:

```
def self.one(name, opts = {})
  class_eval do
    define_method(:"#{name}") do |*args|
      options = opts.dup
      klass   = options.delete(:via) || Trello.const_get(name.to_s.camelize)
      ident   = options.delete(:using) || :id
      klass.find(self.send(ident))
    end
  end
end
```

I understand that [class_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) relates to reflection.

Could someone please explain the purpose of the subclass code line?

My guess would be that it's calling the class member `one` passing `:member_creator` as name and the two trailing args as the `opts` argument. But why would this be called at the class level?

Comment: I can tell you what that method does. It defines a method dynamically at runtime. As for the purpose, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Dogbert "subclass code line" = "line of code from the subclass". Just as "sharp pencil" = "pencil that is sharp" or "dog bowl" = "bowl for the dog".

Comment: @Sergio Thank you for your response. I was being blind, see my response to Teddy's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appears to be a way to DRY up some code used to find a single record by primary key.

You basically pass a class/model name and a method used to get the primary key.

This code:

```
one :member_creator, :via => Member, :using => :member_creator_id
```

Creates this method:

```
def member_creator 
  Member.find(self.member_creator_id)
end
```

Comment: Yes of course - I'm being blind through fatigue. I was aware the superclass definition used `class_eval` to dynamically define a method, but obviously you have to call it to have that method defined. Duh! I'll mark your answer as correct when I'm able to in 5 mins, thank you Teddy.

Comment: p.s. Why wouldn't the author have written it as `one(:member_creator,{:via => Member, :using => :member_creator_id})`? Is my form syntactically correct? It's how I would have written it, but I'm fairly new to Ruby and don't know the caveats of symbols.

Comment: They are both correct, but Rubyist tend to take a "less is more" attitude.  It is a matter of personal preference and consideration of other programmers who will have to maintain the code in the future.

Comment: Ok, message understood. I didn't know you could splat hash operators like that for an argument, interesting! I would have written my own way for clarity. Thank you for responding again Teddy, much appreciated.

Comment: `but Rubyist tend to take a "less is more" attitude` ... + for the attitude